# Cherry tree leaf brown edge

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, fruit-trees, cherries

I bought cordon apple trees and cherry trees 22 May, 2019. recently I start having problems. It was identified as apple scab and recommended Vitax Copper Mixture, which I spread on all the trees apple cherry pear peach,

I chopped all the deceased leaves on the apple tree and sprayed all the new leaves. It seems to be ok, but still you can see a few leaves still look infected. I sprayed them while they were in the container, now they are in the ground.

The cherry trees have like brown at the edges like burning on them. The pears and peaches seem to have like dots on them. Please look at the pictures and advise treatment. I looked online and people keep saying different things.

I really appreciate your help. I spent a lot of money on the trees and I don’t want to lose them.

[image: Leaves with brown discolouration at the edges]

Answer (score 1):

There's something white clustered on the central leaf in your photo - I can't tell if its eggs, insects (like whitefly) or fungal because the photo doesn't magnify sufficiently well. It's probably insects of some sort because there is also evidence of cell damage elsewhere on the leaf; the sap has likely been sucked out by insects or their larvae feeding. Take a magnifying glass and inspect the leaves thoroughly to determine what they are, as well as checking all stems and woody parts and backs of leaves to see if you can find anything else.

For future reference, it's never a good idea to spray plants with treatments unless you have identified the problem correctly; you say you sprayed your cherry trees for scab when the apples showed sign of the infection, but cherry trees do not suffer from scab, so they didn't need the same treatment.